Getting "remote server returned an error (301) moved permanently redirect" error in my ASP.NET Web API
I'm calling a php function in my C# Web API using webclient. And in some instances I get an error

Remote server returned an error (301) moved permanently redirect

as response. In my app I am doing a folder publishing using IIS server. And I enabled precompile during publishing option one time before publishing. Will that be the issue ? Below is the code through which I am accessing the PHP function.
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    var values = new NameValueCollection();
    values["user_id"] = User_Id;
    values["resource_id_org"] = "808";
    values["resource_id"] = "808";
    values["record_id"] = levid.ToString();
    values["action"] = "lr_waiting_for_hr_approval";
    values["process"] = "LeaveRequest";
    values["condition"] = con;

    if (con == "0")
    {
        values["assign_to"] = lev_form.CREATED_BY.ToString();
    }

    values["api"] = "1";
    var response = client.UploadValues(POCOBaseURL.Base_Urls + "project/Backend_PHP/terp_api.php", "POST", values);

    var responseString = Encoding.Default.GetString(response);
    responseString = responseString.Replace("\n", "").Replace("\r", "").Trim();

    if (responseString == " 1" || responseString == "1" || responseString[responseString.Length - 1].ToString() == "1")
    {
        // Other tasks here
    }

I would like to know the possible causes of this error.


Try setting "AllowAutoRedirect = true;" on the webclient.  It is supposed to be true by default, but setting it explicitly might help.  BTW:  WebClient has been dreprecated so you should try to move away from that to HttpClient instead.

If the remote server returns 301 to your code, then the value of POCOBaseURL.Base_Urls + "project/Backend_PHP/terp_api.php" must have been out-of-date. You might contact the administrators of that remote server to learn the latest URL you should use. HTTP to HTTPs redirection is the common cause, but other things can happen too.
